# Web scrape with Selenium webdriver, the first iteration got skipped

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape Copart website by Selenium. The data is presented in rows which include the header. I use this section of code to first get the HTML of the whole page.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests
from selenium import webdriver

filename = "coparttest.csv"
f = open(filename, "w", encoding="utf-8")
headers = "lotnumber,makeyear,makebrand,model,location,sale_date,odometer,doc_type,damage,est_retail_value,current_bid,photos\n"
f.write(headers)

chrome_driver = "/Users/nguyenquanghung/Desktop/webscrape/silenium/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver)

url = "https://www.copart.com/vehicleFinderSearch/?displayStr=BMW,%5B2014%20TO%202019%5D&from=%2FvehicleFinder%2F%3Fintcmp%3Dweb_homepage_hero_vehiclefinder_en&searchStr=%7B%22MISC%22:%5B%22%23MakeCode:BMW%20OR%20%23MakeDesc:BMW%22,%22%23VehicleTypeCode:VEHTYPE_V%22,%22%23LotYear:%5B2014%20TO%202019%5D%22%5D,%22sortByZip%22:false,%22buyerEnteredZip%22:null%7D"
driver.get(url)

page = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")
page_soup = soup(page, "html.parser")
rows = page_soup.findAll("tr",{"role":"row"})
```

Then, I run a for loop to get all the data that I need including each row's photos which only appear when clicking on the zoom button. Therefore, I use
`driver.find_element_by_xpath(...).click()` 
to click on the correspondence button to open up the photo carousel and then get the HTML again by:
`driver. execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")`
to finally get the photos. Note that, I also skip the first row since it is the header. The code work just fine. EXCEPT, the first row get no photos, the first photos are attached to the second row, and so on...It seems like the inner for loop get skip the first iteration. Here is the rest of the code:

```
for index, row in enumerate(rows[1:]):
    lotnumber = row.find("div",{"class":""}).a.text
    makeyear = row.find("span",{"data-uname":"lotsearchLotcenturyyear"}).text
    makebrand = row.find("span",{"data-uname":"lotsearchLotmake"}).text
    model = row.find("span",{"data-uname":"lotsearchLotmodel"}).text
    location = row.find("span",{"data-uname":"lotsearchLotyardname"}).text
    sale_date = row.find("span",{"data-uname":"lotsearchLotauctiondate"}).text
    odometer = row.find("span",{"data-uname":"lotsearchLotodometerreading"}).text.replace(",","")
    doc_type = row.find("span",{"data-uname":"lotsearchSaletitletype"}).text
    damage = row.find("span",{"data-uname":"lotsearchLotdamagedescription"}).text
    est_retail_value = row.find("span",{"data-uname":"lotsearchLotestimatedretailvalue"}).text.replace(",","")

    bid = row.findAll("ul",{"class":"list-unstyled"})[0]
    bid_span = bid.li.ul.li.findAll("span")
    current_bid = bid_span[1].text.replace(",","")

    #Get photo
    #zoom photo
    zoom_button = str(index + 1)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="serverSideDataTable"]/tbody/tr[' + zoom_button + ']/td[2]/div[1]/span').click()
    photo_html = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")
    photo_soup = soup(photo_html, "html.parser")
    # print("photo_soup ---> ",photo_soup)
    photos_list = photo_soup.findAll("img",{"class":"zoomImg"})
    photos = [index]
    for photo in photos_list:
        src = photo["src"]
        photos.append(src)
        print("print photo ---> ",index, src)
    photos = str(photos).replace(","," |")
    #close photo
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="lotImage"]/div/div/div[1]/h4/button').click()

    print("print row ---> ",index,zoom_button,lotnumber,makeyear,makebrand,model,location,sale_date,odometer,doc_type,damage,est_retail_value,current_bid,photos)

    #write row to csv
    f.write(lotnumber+","+makeyear+","+makebrand+","+model+","+location+","+sale_date+","+odometer+","+doc_type+","+damage+","+est_retail_value+","+current_bid+","+photos+"\n")


driver.close()
f.close()
```

Does anyone know why know how/why the first row get empty data?

Answer (score 0):

Try replace code:

```
photo_html = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")
photo_soup = soup(photo_html, "html.parser")
# print("photo_soup ---> ",photo_soup)
photos_list = photo_soup.findAll("img",{"class":"zoomImg"})
photos = [index]
for photo in photos_list:
    src = photo["src"]
    photos.append(src)
    print("print photo ---> ",index, src)
photos = str(photos).replace(","," |")
```

with:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

#...

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="serverSideDataTable"]/tbody/tr[' + zoom_button + ']/td[2]/div[1]/span').click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".zoomImg")))
photos_list = driver.execute_script("return [...document.querySelectorAll('.zoomImg')].map(e=>e.getAttribute('src'))")
for photo in photos_list:
  print("print photo ---> ", photo)
```

You have problem with zoom button index `zoom_button = str(index + 1)`, zoom button should be `zoom_button = str(index)`

Working Java code:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);

driver.get("https://www.copart.com/vehicleFinderSearch/?displayStr=BMW,%5B2014%20TO%202019%5D&from=%2FvehicleFinder%2F%3Fintcmp%3Dweb_homepage_hero_vehiclefinder_en&searchStr=%7B%22MISC%22:%5B%22%23MakeCode:BMW%20OR%20%23MakeDesc:BMW%22,%22%23VehicleTypeCode:VEHTYPE_V%22,%22%23LotYear:%5B2014%20TO%202019%5D%22%5D,%22sortByZip%22:false,%22buyerEnteredZip%22:null%7D");

List<WebElement> rows = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfElementsToBe(By.cssSelector("tbody tr[role=row]"), 21));
for (WebElement row:rows) {
    row.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.searchiconbtn")).click();
    ArrayList<String> photos = (ArrayList)((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return [...document.querySelectorAll('.zoomImg')].map(e=>e.getAttribute('src'))");
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your respond! I just tried this, but unfortunately, it does not do anything better. It really helps shorten my code, but the first photo_lists is still empty. It seems like, after driver.execute_script(...), the inner for loop got skipped, and it jumps straight to print row.

Comment: @LongNguyen you can wait until visibility of element, check my answer update

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. I tried it, but get an error message: `
  selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: ` . It looks like the first photos_list does not content ".zoomImg" in the HTML even after driver.execute_script()

Answer (score 0):

@sers Finally, I found a way to work around it. I have to open and close the zoombutton once before It get any data for the first row. I have no idea why. But, thank you, I have learn WebDriverWait and EC. Here is what i have:

```
zoom_button = str(index + 1)

Open and close for the first time:

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="serverSideDataTable"]/tbody/tr[' + zoom_button + ']/td[2]/div[1]/span').click()
photos_list = driver.execute_script("return [...document.querySelectorAll('.zoomImg')].map(e=>e.getAttribute('src'))")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="lotImage"]/div/div/div[1]/h4/button').click()

Open it again and get data:

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="serverSideDataTable"]/tbody/tr[' + zoom_button + ']/td[2]/div[1]/span').click()
photos_list = driver.execute_script("return [...document.querySelectorAll('.zoomImg')].map(e=>e.getAttribute('src'))")
photos = []
for photo in photos_list:
    photos.append(photo)
    print("print photo ---> ", photo)
photos = str(photos)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="lotImage"]/div/div/div[1]/h4/button').click()
print("print row ---> ",index,zoom_button,lotnumber,makeyear,makebrand,model,location,sale_date,odometer,doc_type,damage,est_retail_value,current_bid,photos)
```

Comment: Try `zoom_button = str(index)`

Comment: @Sers That is the first thing I tried with a thought of the index is offset by 1. But it doesn't do it